# Azerbaijan manat currency

Tags: currency, like-kind-exchange

Currently I have a Azerbaijan paper bill for 50000 manat from the year 1995.
I would like to know if this bill still usable to trade in for USD?

Answer (score 9):

According to [`Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_manat#Second_manat,_1992%E2%80%932006), the "Second manat" was converted to the "third manat" at a ratio of 5,000:1, and "remained valid through 31 December 2006." So **it doesn't appear to be valid now**, but it would only be worth 10 current manat, or about $5.88 USD today.

It may be worth more than that as a collector's item.